# Elasticsearch: fixed data and Pre-search all string combinations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 33 million documents in my db, and this data is fixed. I am providing search-as-you-type and noticed the slowest searches are the ones with the least characters e.g. "a".

My question is, is there a way to pre-calculate all the results for say, any combination of 1,2 or 3 character searches and store in memory? This way when the user types anything up to 3 character, the results will be immediate since they are in memory. Any search that is 4+ character, will be searched as normal.

Hope this is clear, and there is a solution built in ES..

Regards.
R

Comment: Are you using search-as-you-type datatype?https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-as-you-type.html

Comment: @AdamT I'm not, wasn't even aware of it. Is it available from 7.2? What are the benefits? I'm using ngram 1-200